Qt: QCoreApplication / EventLoop in shared library
I need to develop a shared library (Windows dll) based on the Qt framework. In particular, I make use of QTimer, but do not need any GUI elements. However, this library might be used by applications not knowing anything about Qt. I know that the library must provide its own QCoreApplication object for this scenario to make the QTimer object work. But I cannot figure out how to implement this.
Here is a MWE, the functions libInit (initializing a timer for counting) and libGetValue (returning the value of the counter) are exported and used by the calling application:
myqtlib.h
#define LIB_CALLCONV __cdecl

#ifdef BUILD_LIB
    #define LIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define LIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

LIB_API void  LIB_CALLCONV libInit( void );
LIB_API float LIB_CALLCONV libGetValue( void );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

myqtlib.cpp
QTimer Timer;
int Value;

void on_timer()  // Invoked by timer
{
    Value++;
    qDebug() << "*** QtLib *** " << __func__ << "called, setting val to" << Value << "!";
}

void libInit( void )  // Connect and start timer
{
    qDebug() << "*** QtLib ***" << __func__ << "called, QCoreApplication exists:" 
             << (QCoreApplication::instance() != nullptr);
    QObject::connect(&Timer, &QTimer::timeout, on_timer);
    Timer.start(500);
}

float libGetValue( void )  // return current value
{
    return Value;
}

If the shared library / dll is used by a Qt application the code works as intended:
*** QtLib *** libInit called, QCoreApplication exists: true
*** QtLib ***  on_timer called, setting val to 1 !
*** QtLib ***  on_timer called, setting val to 2 !

However, if it is called from an application not using QT I get
*** QtLib *** libInit called, QCoreApplication exists: false
QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread*** 

and the timer slot is not called (as expected since we do not have an event loop running).
I tried several approaches, e.g. this one (complaining that QCoreApplication is not created in the main thread) and these two 1, 2 (blocking my whole library).
Does anyone have an idea how to get this MWE running?
Remark I would like to use Qt in my lib since I use several network related stuff and other features I know how to handle them in Qt. I do not want to dive into other frameworks. But maybe I have a fundamental misunderstanding here...

If you use Qt you need to link with Qt. No way around that.

This comes across as an xy-problem.  What is the real issue you're trying to solve?

While some Qt classes and functions can be used without an event loop, many of them require it. A timer certainly falls in that scenario, and for obvious reasons: it's intended to be non blocking (asynchronous) for the thread in which is run, meaning that it requires an event loop in order to know when to fire up. Any Qt event loop-based function requires at least a QCoreApplication instance, and, obviously, a running event loop. It is possible to create a Q*Application in a separate thread, but that should be done with extreme care: if you ever call any other function from a »

» different thread than that of the Qt application, accessing a non-reentrant or not thread safe object will possibly cause issues (even fatal ones). You need to run the event loop in the thread in which it was created, and everything must be done considering that aspect (thinking of it as the "main" thread). Also remember that only one Q*Application should ever exist, and therefore you should also consider that when trying to access it (or its same-thread-based classes/function) depending on the thread in which it was created.

Put a line in your README that requires the host application to provide the event loop. Fail libInit if there is no QApplication present.
